# Problems with right click menu when choosing file

Tags: touchscreen

I’m using the live system of Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Wayland on a PC with touchscreen. When I long press a file in the file manager,the right click menu appears, but the instant I release my finger it disappears very quickly so I can’t choose the option to operate the file. Is this a general problem or only my operating mistake?
By the way, I can’t open the all applications menu at the lower left corner by simply clicking it.